# Get birthday from customers between now and a week MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im trying to get the records from the database where the customers birthday is between now and a week. I've tried a lot of options and i'm searching for over an hour but i can't find a working solution.
I'm using MYSQL 5.7.19.
This is my query

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, IF(housenumber_addition = "", CONCAT(housenumber,housenumber_addition ), housenumber_addition ) AS adres, sex
FROM customer
WHERE DATE(birthdate) BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Picture of the data:
[image: Data]
Picture of the structure:
[image: Structure]

It's in dutch :(
I also need to get the new age from the customer if it's birthday is between now and a week

Hopefully someone could give me a good and working answer

Thanks in advance

Comment: without looking at your table structure, sample data and expected results it's hard to answer

Comment: I've added some pictures @LelioFaieta

Comment: post your code as text and not as picture. Have a look at [SO guide on how to aks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the birthdate is not in the current year, so your test cannot be true. You need to convert the birthdate into a value in the current year, which you can do by this:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(birthdate), '-', DAY(birthdate)), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

So your query becomes:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, IF(housenumber_addition = "", CONCAT(housenumber,housenumber_addition ), housenumber_addition ) AS adres, sex
FROM customer
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(birthdate), '-', DAY(birthdate)), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

**Update**

As @GordonLinoff points out, this doesn't work if the week overlaps a year end and the birthdate is in the beginning of January (e.g. NOW() = '2018-12-28' and birthdate = '1985-01-02'). To make that case work, it is necessary to also check on the birthdate in `YEAR(NOW())+1` i.e.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, IF(housenumber_addition = "", CONCAT(housenumber,housenumber_addition ), housenumber_addition ) AS adres, sex
FROM customer
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(birthdate), '-', DAY(birthdate)), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY OR
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW())+1, '-', MONTH(birthdate), '-', DAY(birthdate)), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: Ah ok. Now it's working. I've searched everything but nobody coul'd help me. Thanks!

Comment: Do you also know how i can get the age from the customer + 1 @Nick

Comment: SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, NOW()) AS age;

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff I hadn't thought of that scenario. I have posted an edit which fixes that problem.

Comment: @StanvanHeertum please see my edit to the answer to resolve the issue Gordon pointed out.